# How to handle application .env in a docker image?

Tags: php, docker, image, docker-compose

i am about to dockerize my application. The first milestone would be, that i have a docker image, which can run independently on unlimited nodes behind a loadbalancer.

I already split my application layers. Files are stored in AWS s3, MySQL on a remote server, PHP Sessions will be replaced by a JWT.

So far, so good.

**Where i am now:**

- I have a docker environment for my app, put together with
  docker-compose (nginx, php and mysql for local development)
- The app source code is mounted with docker-compose

**Where i want to be:**

- A single build, lets say my-app:latest
- I can create a node, which i can log into, and run my docker image in
- A loadbalancer for all my nodes

**The question:**

How do i handle the .env file of my application **(not from docker-compose)**?

When i build an image, all the application code must be copy into it and not be mounted. So the production .env of my app should also put into it, right?

Whats the best way to handle it?

I hope you understand my question :D
Thanks very much

Comment: You should usually _not_ bundle environment-specific details into your image; the standard approach is to run the same image in all environments if possible.  Whether there's an approach to inject environment variables or files into a container heavily depends on the deployment tool you're using.  Architecturally, it's not wrong to bind-mount _configuration_ into your application (as distinct from _code_, which should be self-contained in the image).  Practically, if you can configure your application principally via environment variables, that can be easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku way is to define [Configvars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) which are exposed to your application as environment variables.

From your code you access them as they were env variables on your local development environment or defined in `docker-compose`